# Python: Create a box/rectangle/table outside of a text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to have a dynamic/perfect box/rectangle/table outside of a text.

In this example, I've a few variables arranged in 3 rows.

The problem started when the length of the strings are different.

How do I fix this problem?

Sample code

```
n1 = 1
i1 = 'Apple'
d1 = 'Fruit'

n2 = 2
i2 = 'Antelope'
d2 = 'Animal'

n3 = 3
i3 = 'Afghanistan'
d3 = 'Country'

print('--------------------------------')
print('| Number | Items | Description |')
print('--------------------------------')
print(f'|    {n1}   | {i1} |    {d1}    |')
print('--------------------------------')
print(f'|    {n2}   | {i2} |    {d2}    |')
print('--------------------------------')
print(f'|    {n3}   | {i3} |    {d3}    |')
print('--------------------------------')
```

Sample output

```
wolf@linux:~$ py script.py 
--------------------------------
| Number | Items | Description |
--------------------------------
|    1   | Apple |    Fruit    |
--------------------------------
|    2   | Antelope |    Animal    |
--------------------------------
|    3   | Afghanistan |    Country    |
--------------------------------
wolf@linux:~$
```

Desired Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ py script.py 
--------------------------------------
| Number | Items       | Description |
--------------------------------------
|    1   | Apple       |    Fruit    |
--------------------------------------
|    2   | Antelope    |    Animal   |
--------------------------------------
|    3   | Afghanistan |    Country  |
--------------------------------------
wolf@linux:~$
```

Comment: use [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) module. there are various types of styles you can specify the desired style using `tablefmt` argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate) module for automating the spacing in each cell. Try the following :

```
from tabulate import tabulate
n1 = 1
i1 = 'Apple'
d1 = 'Fruit'

n2 = 2
i2 = 'Antelope'
d2 = 'Animal'

n3 = 3
i3 = 'Afghanistan'
d3 = 'Country'
    
table_rows = [
    ['Number', 'Items', 'Description'],
    [n1, i1, d1],
    [n2, i2, d2],
    [n3, i3, d3]
]
print(tabulate(table_rows, tablefmt="fancy_grid"))
```

Output :

```
╒════════╤═════════════╤═════════════╕
│ Number │ Items       │ Description │
├────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ 1      │ Apple       │ Fruit       │
├────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ 2      │ Antelope    │ Animal      │
├────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ 3      │ Afghanistan │ Country     │
╘════════╧═════════════╧═════════════╛
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 (upvote) to you. I've another question about tabulate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879273/how-to-combine-join-table-in-python-tabulate

Answer (score -1):

You can use `tabulate` module
Here is the code for the same

```
from tabulate import _table_formats, tabulate

table = [[1,"Apple","Fruit"], [2,"Antelope", "Animal"], [3,"Afghanistan", "Country"]]
headers = ["Number", "Items","Description"]

print(tabulate(table, headers, tablefmt="simple"))
```

Edit : Removed the link as it violated forum rules

Comment: you can't post link only answers. add an example or some explanation how this will solves the OP problem

Comment: Thanks @kiteshjain

+1 (upvote) to you. I've another question about tabulate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879273/how-to-combine-join-table-in-python-tabulate

Comment: @deadshot Have updated the post to remove link and added example

Comment: @kiteshjain It is not necessary to remove the link. The link is helpful, it's just shouldn't be the focus of your answer. It should be an extra for further reading and your answer should include the main important parts of the link. Also it is most certainly unnecessary to edit the answer saying that you removed the link