# How to combine/join table in Python tabulate?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been playing around with Python `tabulate` module after found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62876323/python-create-a-box-rectangle-table-outside-of-a-text/62876451).

Instead of having separate box when reading it from file, would it be possible to combine/join it?

Here is the sample code and output.

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat file.txt 
Apples
Bananas
Cherries
wolf@linux:~$
```

Python code

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat script.py 
from tabulate import tabulate

with open(r'file.txt') as f:
    for i,j in enumerate(f.read().split(), 1):
        table = [[ i,j ]]
        print(tabulate(table, tablefmt="grid"))
wolf@linux:~$
```

Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ python script.py 
+---+--------+
| 1 | Apples |
+---+--------+
+---+---------+
| 2 | Bananas |
+---+---------+
+---+----------+
| 3 | Cherries |
+---+----------+
wolf@linux:~$
```

Desired Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ python script.py 
+---+----------+
| 1 | Apples   |
+---+----------+
| 2 | Bananas  |
+---+----------+
| 3 | Cherries |
+---+----------+
wolf@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a single table & print that instead of creating `table` 3 times & printing each:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

with open(r'temp.txt') as f:
    table = []
    for i,j in enumerate(f.read().split(), 1):
        table.append([ i,j ])
    print(tabulate(table, tablefmt="grid"))
```

Result:

```
+---+----------+
| 1 | Apples   |
+---+----------+
| 2 | Bananas  |
+---+----------+
| 3 | Cherries |
+---+----------+
```